# Dry run for SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My project had around 150 SSIS packages, I wanted to run all my packages to see if its working. The source I am using is a huge (25 million records).

The main problem I'm finding now is the package runs for 20 mins and errors at the bottom.

Is there a easy way to do a dry run or running the entire packages for fraction of data, so that I can run all the package and see if its actually working before doing the initial run.

Source: Oracle

ETL tool: SSIS

Target: SQL database

Comment: What sorts of errors are you running into? Some errors can be caught w/o having to run the package (i.e. metadata mismatch errors). Others, however, require the data to actually flow (e.g. pk/fk violations).

The other option is to make your packages more resilient. That is, instead of failing outright, log to a table for post-hoc analysis. Something like the name of the table, PK of the row that failed, and the error message should get you a long way there.

Comment: there are lot of c# scripts used in the packages, just wanted to make sure its all working